# Return the head of the linked list after swapping the values of the kth node from the beginning and the kth node from the end (the list is 1-indexed)

Tags: python

I am learning python and playing around with some random quiz's and I come across this question and I have my solution but when I googled the solution for this problem, I see a bigger code than the code I pasted. Can someone please help where I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

You are given the head of a linked list, and an integer k.

Return the head of the linked list after swapping the values of the kth node from the beginning and the kth node from the end (the list is 1-indexed).

My Answer is :

```
`head = [7 ,9 ,6 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,3 ,0 ,9 ,5]
 k = 5
 swap_1 = head[k-1]
 swap_2 = head[-k]
 head[k-1] = swap_2
 head[-k] = swap_1
 print(head)`
```

how my solution is different than other solutions.

Comment: You don't have a linked list, you have a plain old list, like an array. In a linked list you'd have one list element point to another, hence linking them.

Answer (score 0):

@saipavan welcome to the stack-overflow.

What you have is a "normal" list and not a linked-list.

### How they are different:

"Normal" list has a items stored in consecutive memory blocks. You can imagine values one after another. This allows you getting n-th element in array very simply. The drawback to the "normal" list is that if you would like to insert element in the middle of the list, you need to move all the elements one slot "down".

The Linked-list contains head of the list (the first element), and inside this element is stored value + index (address) of a memory block of the next element. In next element you found value + index of a memory block and so on... It is "harder" to get to a n-th element, (because you need to actually walk the path to a n-th element), but insertion in very easy - just change the value of an memory index. Another benefit is, that you don't need consecutive block of memory. This array could be scattered across the memory (RAM) because you always has an address to a next element.

### Why should I care?

Well, in "normal" programming you probably shouldn't. In normal size arrays, when the performance doesn't need to be perfect you could always use "normal" array. In reality in most cases this is enough.

### If you want to get the answer to a task:

Firs of all you need to create this class Linked-List.

Linked list is constructed by elements of an list (containing value + address to next element) and a list, that holds head (beginning of the array)

```
# This is a class for elements
class Element:

    # This is init method to create element. You create it with value
    def __init__(self, value=None):
      # copy value to object
      self.value = value
      # for now address of next element is None
      self.nextElement = None

# This is class that will hold Linked List
class LinkedList:
    
    # Init empty list -> this mean that it doesn't have first element yet
    def __init__(self):
      self.head = None

# Init the Linked list
list = LinkedList()
# add first element to a list
list.head = Element(7)
# Add new element and save it to a nextElement property
list.head.nextElement = Element(9)
# And add next...
list.head.nextElement.nextElement = Element(6)
#....
```

I left the step by step code so you can understand and get the fill for it. But You can see that this is not very nice...

Ok we could add method add value to a list

```
# This is class that will hold Linked List
class LinkedList:
    
    # Init empty list -> this mean that it doesn't have first element yet
    def __init__(self):
      self.head = None
      # Store the last value
      self.tail = None

    def addValue(self, value):
        # create new element
        new_element = Element(value)
        # if there is no head, this is first element (and last)
        if not self.head:
          self.head = new_element
        else:
          # if this is not first element add it as next element to a tail
          self.tail.nextElement = new_element
        # move a tail
        self.tail = Element(value)
```

Ok so now we know how to create list

```
# Init the Linked list
list = LinkedList()
list.addValue(9)
list.addValue(7)
list.addValue(6)
...
```

To get the 5-th element form beginning you could do:

```
a = list.head.nextElement.nextElement.nextElement.nextElement
```

And get the 5-th element from end you could extend the code:

```
# This is a class for elements
class Element:

    # This is init method to create element. You create it with value
    def __init__(self, value=None):
      # copy value to object
      self.value = value
      # for now address of next element is None
      self.nextElement = None
      self.previousElement = None




# This is class that will hold Linked List
class LinkedList:
    
    # Init empty list -> this mean that it doesn't have first element yet
    def __init__(self):
      self.head = None
      # Store the last value
      self.tail = None

    def addValue(self, value):
        # create new element
        new_element = Element(value)
        # if there is no head, this is first element (and last)
        if not self.head:
          self.head = new_element
        else:
          # if this is not first element add it as next element to a tail 
          new_element.previousElement = self.tail
          self.tail.nextElement = new_element
        # move a tail
        self.tail = Element(value)
```

and then

```
 b = list.tail.previousElement.previousElement.previousElement.previousElement
```

To swap those elements you need to change the reference indexes

```
b_previous = b.previousElement
b_next = b.nextValue
b.previousElement = a.previousElement
b.nextValue = a.nextValue
a.previousElement = b_previous
a.nextValue = b_next
```

Ok This should be it...

Ok the code for getting the n-th element is ugly and the swap as well...
Try to add 3 more functions to a LinkedList object to do it nicer.